# How to create a span elements itself using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, scripting, dynamic-programming, dynamic-html

Hey am new to javascript but putting my all efforts I have written a javascript to copy the text inside `<p></p>` elements. I have written the code completely but my problem is I have to create span elements repeatedly. So can any one help me. My javascript

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{

  const createtextbox=function(text){
    let el=document.createElement('textarea');
      el.style.position = 'fixed';
      el.style.left = '0';
      el.style.top = '0';
      el.style.opacity = '0';
      el.value = text;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    return el;
  };

  const shortmessage=function(e,m,t){
    let span=e.parentNode.querySelector( 'span' );
      span.innerText=m;
    setTimeout(()=>{span.innerText=''},700 * t)
    span.classList.add("copystatusalert");
     setTimeout(function() {span.classList.remove("copystatusalert")},700);
  };

  const copytoclipboard=function(e){
    // create the hidden textarea and add the text from the sibling element
    let n=createtextbox( this.parentNode.querySelector('p').innerHTML );
      n.focus();
      n.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(n);

    // flash a message in the SPAN-clear after 2s
    shortmessage( this, 'Copied!', 0.7 );
  };

  /*
    Find a reference to ALL buttons that are used to copy
    text from a sibling element and assign an event handler 
    to process every button click.
  */
  document.querySelectorAll('button.copystatus').forEach( bttn=>{
    bttn.addEventListener( 'click', copytoclipboard )
  });
})
```

My html

```
<div class='englishstatus'>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Life is good when you have books</p> 
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Google is a open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Ferrets are better than rats</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I need the span elements to create repeatedly so can anyone help me so that it can create itself a span elements. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: You use `.createElement()` same as you did with `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your JS code and put it to the straight point by adding the span elements dynamically. You can refactor it, separate the code snippets into different functions as you want. I just want to make the implementation logic straight forward here.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.copystatus.btn');

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const quote = e.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
    
    const copyText = document.createElement('textarea');
    copyText.value = quote;
    
    document.body.appendChild(copyText);
    copyText.select();
    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(copyText);
    
    
    const span = document.createElement('span');
    span.textContent = 'copied';
    e.target.parentElement.appendChild(span);
    setTimeout(()=> {
        span.remove();
    }, 700)
    
  })
})
```

```html
<div class='englishstatus'>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Life is good when you have books</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Google is a open source library by Larry Page and Sergey Brin!</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='car'>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Cats are better than dogs.</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
    </div>
    <div class='latestatus'>
      <p>Ferrets are better than rats</p>
      <button class='copystatus btn'>Copy</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```